# Promisify all methods with Node.js util module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a redis util that looks like:

```
const redis = require('redis')
const { promisify } = require('util')
const client = redis.createClient({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: '6379'
})

module.exports = {
  get: promisify(client.get).bind(client),
  hget: promisify(client.hget).bind(client),
  set: promisify(client.set).bind(client),
  mset: promisify(client.mset).bind(client),
  hset: promisify(client.hset).bind(client),
  hmset: promisify(client.hmset).bind(client),
  ...
}
```

I'd like to rewrite this without all of the repetition.  How would I export the client functions with `promisify` iterated over each method?

Initially, I looked into `Object.keys(client)` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(client)` as a starting point for grabbing the method names to map over, but neither of these arrays contained them.

Edit: This is closer, is there a better way to phrase this?

```
const promisifiedClient = {}

for (const fn in Object.getPrototypeOf(client)) {
  if (typeof client[fn] === 'function') {
    promisifiedClient[fn] = promisify(client[fn]).bind(client)
  }
}

module.exports = promisifiedClient
```

Edit2: Maybe this works (if it's not without some odd side effect of promisifying functions I might not need / want to promisify?)

```
const redisFunctionList = Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(client))

const promisifiedRedis = redisFunctionList.reduce((acc, functionName) => {
  acc[functionName] = promisify(client[functionName]).bind(client)
  return acc
}, {})

module.exports = promisifiedRedis
```

Comment: They're probably inherited from a prototype object. Try either a `for … in` loop or prototype chain traversal (`Object.getPrototypeOf`) on `client` until you see the methods that you are looking for.

Comment: what about passing the whole thing into Promisify.all
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Erh, Jacob, `Promise.all` is not `Promisify.all`...

Comment: Oh, oops. I forgot Bluebird exists because of Async/Await lol

Comment: Hate to think there isn't an npm module for redis promises already

Comment: Oh...ok I know where I screwed up here. Ignore my ravings of a fool.

Comment: Bluebirds Promisify.all(theThings) ...Maybe

https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#bluebird-promises

BlueBirds PromiseAll http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) package, and then could promisify the redis client simply.

```js
const redis = require("redis");
const bluebird = require("bluebird");
const client = new redis.RedisClient();

/// promise based client of redis
/// storing it in a variable helps with intellisense
const promiseClient = bluebird.promisifyAll(client);

const main = async () => {
  /// After that, we just call the default methods with an Async in the end
  /// For Example:
  /// client.get becomes client.getAsync
  /// client.set becaomes client.setAsync
  const data = await promiseClient.getAsync("foo");
  console.log(data);
  const message = await promiseClient.quitAsync();
  console.log(message);
};

main();

module.exports = promiseClient;
```